Bootstrap datepicker the years that more than the minDate
I have the issue with the boostrap datepicker. I set the datepicker with minDate: '-11m' and the datepicker show only 11 month before today (In this case: July 2023 - June 2024), but the datepicker show the year that suppossed to not be show which is 2022 and there is a left arrow in 2023.
enter image description here
            $('#tanggalTrx').datepicker({
                clearBtn: false,
                format: 'yyyy-mm',
                autoclose: true,
                minViewMode: 1,
                changeYear: true,
                calenderWeeks: true,
                minDate: '-1y',
                startDate: '-11m',
                endDate: '0d',
                toggleActive: true,
            });

How I disable the 2022 so it's only show 2023 and 2024. Thank you
I have try search in internet and read the documentation but it's not help

Your code seems to work just as you expect, the year 2022 is not displayed

But in 2023, it shouldn't have a left button and only show right button

Here is your code running, I don't know which bootstrap and jquery version you are using, here I used the latest versions


$('#tanggalTrx').datepicker({
    clearBtn: false,
    format: 'yyyy-mm',
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    changeYear: true,
    calenderWeeks: true,
    minDate: '-1y',
    startDate: '-11m',
    endDate: '0d',
    toggleActive: true,
  });
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-LsnSViqQyaXpD4mBBdRYeP6sRwJiJveh2ZIbW41EBrNmKxgr/LFZIiWT6yr+nycvhvauz8c2nYMhrP80YhG7Cw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-34s5cpvaNG3BknEWSuOncX28vz97bRI59UnVtEEpFX536A7BtZSJHsDyFoCl8S7Dt2TPzcrCEoHBGeM4SUBDBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


<div id="tanggalTrx"></div>




I'm using version 1.8.0 btw, but still not working
